stuck cartridge nut holding Moen 1224 cartridge
I have a stuck cartridge nut holing the Moen 1224 cartridge for my Chateau 4945. Moen has sent me the replacement parts.
I have the removal tool. So far I have tried vinegar soaking over night per Moen,
WD 40.  I tried putting a cold pack to see if the plastic would harden enough to loosen the nut with the tool.  Next I tried hot compress to try to soften the plastic nut enough to loosen it.
Both did not work.  Finally I tried a hair dryer applying direct heat on the tool and nut.  Seems to loosen a few clicks at time.  The nut by now is pretty beat up.
I am looking for suggestions cause I do not want to call a plumber.

Your info on make and model is great, however some pics would allow us to see what you see and possibly motivate a memory of a method used.

You can also try Liquid Wrench (or a homebrew concoction of acetone + automatic transmission fluid in equal parts)
